# Elasticsearch 6.5 query scoring changed, how do we get the ES 5 type results?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene

I am making a recommender with Elasticsearch. I know what people have bought and this forms the query. The index is of items and has a field that contains items bought in common.

We were using ES 5 and the following query finds the highest score, meaning items that have the most in common with the query. But this query in ES 6 returns only score = 1.0 and so no longer find the most similar items.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "bought": [
              "iPad Pro",
              "iPhone 8"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How do we get the same results with an ES 6 query?

Comment: this is the nature of terms query, I would expect. IT would be better to utilize a bit different query

Comment: Ok, I see that now but what can we do to get the same scores and results with ES 6?

Answer (score 0):

It’s listed as a [breaking change](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-6.0.html#_changes_to_queries) in the Elasticsearch 6.0. Basically, `terms` query now always return scores equal to `1`

Unfortunately, as I stated already, it would be very difficult to have exactly the same behaviour, but according to your logic in question - I would recommend to use boolean query, e.g.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "bought" : "Ipad PRO" } },
        { "term" : { "bought" : "Iphone XS" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In this case you would be able to mimic the same terms query behaviour, but also keep the score related to exactly logic you want. If person just bought 1 thing out of 2 score will be less`

Comment: "terms" always returns score = 1 now, thanks. But how do I get Cosine similarity now? There is no mention in your link of what to replace it with. I think your query still does not give me scores I want, it just does an ORed query where each match returns a 1 or 0. My full query is much more complicated and uses "terms" in must, must_not, and in should with boosts with ANDing and ORing of sets of terms. All of which is now broken it would seem.

Comment: this query works to some extent but in ES 5.6 matching 2 of 5 was less than matching 2 of 4, now the above query give the same score in both cases, event though the matching is NOT the same. What I want to do is really no different than asking how similar my query is to the `bought` field of every item -- and return the highest. The essence of search, which should rank 2 of 4 higher than 2 of 5. I am just bypassing analysis of terms from free text.